# How to refresh new tab after opening with target_blank

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I have a button and in href i have a url. I provide url with a model in razor view. I open it in new tab with target_blank and i want to refresh page after 1 seconds i opened it. I want to refresh it like i press f5 in keyboard.
My HTML:

```
<a href="@Html.Raw(item.Image)" onclick="refresh()" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Show</a>
```

JS:

```
function refresh() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload(true);
    }, 1000);
}
```

it refreshes the page but it refreshes the page i came from, it does not refresh the new opened tab with target_blank. And the key is i don't want to go any url after opening page like going the same url etc. i just want to refresh the page like i press f5.

Comment: The Javascript in one tab is incapable of controlling the state of other tabs (aside from opening new ones). This is a security barrier that's enforced by the browser. If you own the second URL, you can add new javascript to that page.